# What is the FDG for naming boolean properties?

Tags: c#, .net, design-guidelines

What is the [Framework Design Guideline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) for naming boolean properties? If there isn't one, then what's your recommendation?

Let's say I have a `User` class, and I need a property that specifies if the user is enabled or not. These are the options I can think of:

- Enable
- Enabled
- IsEnabled
- Disable
- Disabled
- IsDisabled

Also, if the BL says that the user must be disabled by default and explicitly enabled, should I prefer an 'enable' variation, considering that the default value for `System.Boolean` is `false` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Framework Design Guidelines (Brad Abrahms and Krzysztof Cwalina) say to use either `Enabled` or `IsEnabled` (section [3.6.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)). They say to use affirmative phrases (ie. CanSeek instead of CantSeek), and to use the most readable version (ie. Created is more readable than IsCreated).

I would personally use `Enabled` in your case, with a default value of `false`. `User.Enabled` reads well and is clear in what its meaning is.

Comment: It's interesting how some code from Microsoft does not follow this guideline, e.g.
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler has a static property DisableMvcResponseHeader. Why did they choose to use Disable? is it because it's enabled by default and bool is false by default, therefore it's NOT disabled by default?

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid the "disabled" variation, since a double negative like "disabled = false" is much harder to comprehend than "enabled = true".

I'd also prefer an adjectival form for a property to the verb "enable", which would be a better method name.

That narrows it down to "enabled" or "isEnabled", which is probably a matter of personal style & convention. The latter emphasizes that it's a bool; the former is more succinct.